# What would be the pricing for using Amazon SES from a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I am configuring Amazon SES to send emails, through a lambda function. I am trying to understand the pricing model for doing this.
As per the AWS docs, the pricing is as follows:

> **Sending email from an application hosted in Amazon EC2**
> $0 for the first 62,000 emails you send each month, and $0.10 for every 1,000 emails you send after that.

> **Sending email from an email client or other software package**
> $0.10 for every 1,000 emails you send.

Where do lambda functions fit into this pricing scenario? While I do understand AWS would host lambda functions on some variant of a virtual instance, will the pricing model of an EC2 instance apply while invoking SES through lambdas as well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)

> With AWS Lambda, you pay only for what you use. You are charged based on the number of requests for your functions and the duration, the time it takes for your code to execute.

So you would be charged based on the execution time of your Lambda (will likely be milliseconds per call).

> will the pricing model of an EC2 instance apply while invoking SES through lambdas as well?

It seems like there is some confusion regarding this issue.  The same question is addressed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/b7uek5/aws_ses_pricing_on_lambda_same_as_ec2_or_full/).  It's unclear but it seems like it will be cheaper to run on Lambda than EC2.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Matthew. However, what I meant to ask was the pricing for amazon SES, not the pricing for using a lambda. Will the pricing for using SES through lambda be the same as that through an EC2 instance, or as that through an external client?

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is quite old, my answer may help others. AWS updated their pricing page of SES and Lambda pricing is mentioned explicitly at the end of the page:

> When you call Amazon SES from an application hosted in Amazon EC2 or
> via AWS Lambda, you can send 62,000 messages per month at no charge.
> This Free Usage Tier benefit does not expire.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/

Comment: This is now outdated, as the copy and free tier limits have changed

Answer (score 1):

Update Dec 2022: The comment by @user3221512 no longer appears to apply. The wording appears to have been changed to,

> As part of AWS Free Tier, AWS SES offers 62,000 Outbound Messages per month >to any recipient when you call Amazon SES from an Amazon EC2 instance >directly or through AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and 1,000 Inbound Messages per >month.

Comment: Even if it does say that, I've just tested it and emails sent by SES through Lambda appear in the "Free Tier" section in the Cost Explorer.